# dynamic jPanel buttons actionCommand

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I would like to ask a question related to dynamic `button` `actionPerformed`. I have `jFrame` with content menu which will reference to dynamic `jPanel1` by `cardLayout` and `jButton1`. Dynamic `jPanel1` contain `saveButton`. I attached `Test ActionListener` to `jButton1`. The problem that I am facing is I have set `actionCommand` to `jPanel1.saveButton` as shown in below code. And when I click `jButton1` output I am getting `2` and `3`. I was expected that `2nd` and `3rd` `jPanel1.SaveButton` also was clicked, but just `3rd` `jPanel1.saveButton` was clicked. How do I get that `2nd` and `3rd` `jPanel1.SaveButton` were clicked?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Test implements ActionListener {

    public Test() {
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        for (int i = 0; i<2; i++){
           jPanel1.save.setActionCommand(String.valueOf(i+2));
           String n = jPanel1.save.getActionCommand();
           jPanel1.save.doClick();
           System.out.println("jPanel1: " + n);
        }

           System.out.println("The action have been performed");
    }

    public static void main(String[] agrs) {
           JButton but = new JButton();
           but.addActionListener(new Test());
           but.doClick();
    }  
}

Output:
jPanel1: 2
jPanel1: 3
```

Comment: `Test` Please give your test classes more descriptive names. A thousand people before you chose that name, and I'm sick of deleting class from my generic test package. As it stands, I don't understand the question. *"How do I get that 2nd and 3rd jPanel1.SaveButton were clicked?"* If `2` is printed, it was the second. If `3` appears, it was the 3rd. More generally: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I meant that `jPanel1.save.doClick();` was performed just for dynamic `jPanel1` with `actionCommand 3`. In case of `jPanel1` with `actionCommand 2` no sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you want every `ActionListener` instance refer to a different `JPanel` you can pass a reference to that `JPanel' to its constructor :

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();   
JButton but = new JButton();
but.addActionListener(new Test(panel1));
```

And change the constructor to use that reference:

```
JPanel panel; 
public Test(JPanel panel) {
    this.panel = panel;
}
```